# Kotlin: storing and invoking functions with type parameter in generic collections

Tags: generics, kotlin, covariance, rules, contravariance

I am writing simple expert system in Kotlin. Let's start with the facts. I implemented `Fact` as follows:

```
data class Fact<T>(val id: String, val value: T)
```

To give an example, it's instance would look like this:

```
val f1 = Fact<Boolean>("adult", true) // Fact: "the person is adult"
```

Then, I implemented a `Condition` class. It looks as follows:

```
data class Condition<T>(val id: String, val question: String, val evaluation: (T) -> Boolean)
```

In that way I can store conditon that sounds like *The age is 18 years old or higher*

```
val c1 = Condition<Int>("age", "What is your age"){it >= 18}
```

Due to type parameter I can store condition that takes e.g. String type parameter.

```
val c2 = Condition<String>("country", "Where do you live?"){it == "Poland"}
```

We have discussed `Fact` and `Condition` classes. Now it is time for a `Rule`. Rule looks like: `set_of_premises => fact`. That means set of premises implies the fact. For example

```
{person A is at least 18 years old, A lives in Poland} => A is adult // pseudocode
```

I implemented this as follows:

```
class Rule(
            val conditions: Set<Condition<out Any>>,
            val conclusion: Fact<out Any>
           )
```

I store rules in a list. It's type is `List<Rule>`, since `Rule` does not take type parameter (it is meant to store `Condition`s of different types `T`).
And now comes the actual problem:
I cannot use the function `evaluetion: (T) -> Boolean` from condition that is part of rule stored in list of rules. That is what I mean:

```
val evaluationFuns = listOfRules[0].conditions.map{it.evaluation} // the type is `List<(Nothing)->Boolean>`
```

**Since the input parameter is Nothing, I cannot use the evaluation function for evaluationg facts.** (I cannot apply that function to anything). I read a lot about variance, tried playing with `out` and `in` but nothing helps.

Comment: It's not clear what the map logic should do. `Condition` doesn't have `value`, only `Fact` does. Could you clarify this part?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin Thanks for your comment, I fixed it. Now I hope it's clear

Comment: When you write `Condition<out Any>`, you are saying that `condition` can only spit out `Any`, but the `T` parameter appears in `in` position. So the only thing you can pass is `Nothing`, that is _nothing_. Try removing `out`

Comment: @gpunto sadly, it doesn't work either, because of TypeMismatch while crating the set of `conditions` (required: `Set<Condition<<Any>>`, found `Set<Condition<<out Any>>`). It seems like I need both `in` and `out` functionality.

Comment: Well, that cannot work because, for example, a function `(Int) -> Bool` is not equal to a function `(Any) -> Bool`. The first only accepts `Int`s. What is your use case for having a collection of functions where you don't know the actual types? Wouldn't it be better to have a `Rule<T>`?

Comment: thanks @gpunto. Let's look at the rule that I mentioned above in pseudocode. It decides weather person is adult based on their age (`Int`) and country name (`String`). That I cannot use single `T` type for whole rule :(

Comment: I think you should parametrize everything over `Person`. So, for example, your conditions could be something like: `val c1 = Condition<Person>("age", "What is your age"){it.age >= 18}` and `val c2 = Condition<Person>("country", "Where do you live?"){it.homeCountry == "Poland"}`

Comment: @gpunto I think I will give it a try, thank you

Comment: Actually I worked out a slighty different way, which worked fine. It doesn't use Person class, although @gpunto 's comment was highly inspiring. When I finish I will post the anwer here and maybe write a paper on it on Medium.